# How to test smtp protocol's 250-PIPELINING function?

Tags: email, smtp

the smtp server support 250-PIPELINING function,so I can send many smtp command to server in one time
[image]

but I don't know how to test it?

I cann't find the 250-PIPELINING option on MUA (like outlook)

so I want to test it by telnet

I send two "rcpt to" command in one line,but server told me wrong:

[image]

so how can I test the 250-PIPELINING function?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send 2 commands on the same line. The command syntax is the same for PIPELINED commands - the difference is that you can send multiple commands without having to wait for a response first.

The only way to test this via telnet is to first construct a text file with multiple commands and then copy & paste that into your telnet app.

Comment: Thanks,I have test it.Is there some MUA support PIPELINED ? If there is no popular MUA support this,it's means this function is useless?

Comment: I suspect many popular clients support it. Anything that uses my MailKit library supports it out of the box. It's very trivial to support.

Comment: I can't find the PIPELINED  option even on Outlook.Can you find it?

Comment: Why would it need a user visible option?